# In how many ways can you pick $m$ cats from $n$ cats if $2$ given cats must never be together at the $m$-group?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways can you pick $m$ cats from $n$ cats if $2$ given cats must never be together at the $m$-group?

Is it $C(n,m)-C(n-2,m-2)$,  $C(n-2,m)+C(n-1,m)+C(n-1,m)$ or something else?

Comment: Very valid question, it's not just combinatorics and permutations though. You have to step up your Maths knowlegde to combinatorial designs and much more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first answer is correct, the second is wrong.

The first formula amounts to (all combos) - (combos with both the cats together)

The second formula **tries** to compute (neither cat in combo) + (cat 1 in combo) + (cat 2 in combo), but fails to see that the 2nd and 3rd terms do not **guarantee** the specific cat actually being in the combo.

The correct expression would be $\dbinom{n-2}{m} + 2\dbinom11\dbinom{n-2}{m-1}=  \dbinom{n-2}{m} + 2\dbinom{n-2}{m-1}$

Answer (score -1):

Both answers are true. To see the equality you can use $\dbinom{n}{k}=\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}+\dbinom{n-1}{k}$.

Comment: Both answers may be the same, but not necessarily true. Please calculate for $n = 4$ and $m = 1,2,3$ the expected answers. I don't think the answers are valid for the cats question.

Comment: But for example if I apply the numbers n=12 and m=7 then the first one gives 672 but the second one gives 780 combinations

Comment: OP hasn't used the identity you are quoting !